# Priority_queue and input stream iterator

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

```
int main()
{
    list<char> letters;
    priority_queue<char, vector<char>, less<char>>letters_trans;

    cout << "Enter some sentence: " << endl << endl;

    std::istream_iterator<char> input(cin), input_end;

    copy(input, input_end, back_inserter<list<char>>(letters));

    for each(char letter in letters)
    {
        letters_trans.push(letter);
    }

    while(!letters_trans.empty())
    {
        cout << letters_trans.top();
        letters_trans.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see I have a school project to transfer cin to priority queue. Well I "kinda did it... What I did is input **istream_iterator** to list

then to priority_queue, which is very inefficient I guess in the long run.So is there a way to transfer directly cin to priority_queue without a middle man. I tried doing it but the copy function wont let me have priority_queue as an arguement.

Answer (score 4):

You can construct `priority_queue` (or any std container) from pair of iterator `[first, last)`. From [cpp reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/priority_queue/):

```
template <class InputIterator>
         priority_queue ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                          const Compare& x = Compare(),
                          const Container& y = Container() );
```

> first,last
>
> Input iterators to the initial and final positions in a
>   sequence. The range used is [first,last), which includes all the
>   elements between first and last, including the element pointed by
>   first but not the element pointed by last.  The function template type
>   can be any type of input iterator.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::istream_iterator<char, std::vector<char> > input(std::cin), input_end;
  std::priority_queue<char> q(input, input_end);

  while (!q.empty())
  {
    std::cout << q.top() << std::endl;
    q.pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's using the constructor that takes two InputIterators - input and input_end are not pointers.

Comment: @AlanStokes Thanks. Modified. Constructor signature was copy pasted from [sgi](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html).

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, this should work:

```
std::priority_queue<char> q(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<char>());
```

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<char> q(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<char>());

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        std::cout << q.top() << '\n';
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the intermediate vector? A priority queue can be directly constructed from a pair of input iterators.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Indeed, I had missed that constructor. Fixed, thanks!